# Can you make a shorter version of member.created_at in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

Is there a way for `member.created_at` to not be that long, for example be like this: **2019-06-22** instead of **2019-06-22 10:38:56.223000** ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`member.created_at` returns a `datetime` type. You can do:

```py
creation_date = member.created_at
creation_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

See here: [python_datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime)